# question in install third party package on ROS

Tags: ros, catkin-make, github

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**I want to install a third party package which is**

Source: https://github.com/labust/labust-ros-pkg.git

Dependencies:

Description: The labust_control package contains all the low and high-level controllers used for the vehicles and platforms at LABUST.

**and i did several step below:**

```
$ mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
$ git clone https://github.com/labust/labust-ros-pkg.git
$ cd ..
$ catkin_make
```

**while cankin_make it returns many mistakes I don't know how to solve**

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:71 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package navcon_msgs.

  Set navcon_msgs_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
  for navcon_msgs.  The file will have one of the following names:

    navcon_msgsConfig.cmake
    navcon_msgs-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  labust-ros-pkg/labust_execution/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Boost version: 1.46.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   graph
-- checking for module 'eigen3'
--   found eigen3, version 3.0.5
-- Found Eigen: /usr/include/eigen3 
-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)
-- +++ skipping metapackage: 'labust_framework'
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'labust_launchers'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(labust-ros-pkg/labust_launchers)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'labust_uwsim'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(labust-ros-pkg/labust_uwsim)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'matlogger'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(labust-ros-pkg/matlogger)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'snippets'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(labust-ros-pkg/snippets)
-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'ident_so'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(labust-ros-pkg/ident_so)
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:71 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package navcon_msgs.

  Set navcon_msgs_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
  for navcon_msgs.  The file will have one of the following names:

    navcon_msgsConfig.cmake
    navcon_msgs-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  labust-ros-pkg/ident_so/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- +++ processing catkin package: 'labust_control'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(labust-ros-pkg/labust_control)
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:71 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package auv_msgs.

  Set auv_msgs_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for
  auv_msgs.  The file will have one of the following names:

    auv_msgsConfig.cmake
    auv_msgs-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  labust-ros-pkg/labust_control/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:71 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package navcon_msgs.

  Set navcon_msgs_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
  for navcon_msgs.  The file will have one of the following names:

    navcon_msgsConfig.cmake
    navcon_msgs-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  labust-ros-pkg/labust_control/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:71 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package tf2_ros.

  Set tf2_ros_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for
  tf2_ros.  The file will have one of the following names:

    tf2_rosConfig.cmake
    tf2_ros-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  labust-ros-pkg/labust_control/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- +++ processing catkin package: 'labust_mission'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(labust-ros-pkg/labust_mission)
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:71 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package decision_making.

  Set decision_making_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration
  file for decision_making.  The file will have one of the following names:

    decision_makingConfig.cmake
    decision_making-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  labust-ros-pkg/labust_mission/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:71 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package decision_making_parser.

  Set decision_making_parser_DIR to the directory containing a CMake
  configuration file for decision_making_parser.  The file will have one of
  the following names:

    decision_making_parserConfig.cmake
    decision_making_parser-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  labust-ros-pkg/labust_mission/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:71 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package random_numbers.

  Set random_numbers_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration
  file for random_numbers.  The file will have one of the following names:

    random_numbersConfig.cmake
    random_numbers-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  labust-ros-pkg/labust_mission/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:71 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package tf2_ros.

  Set tf2_ros_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for
  tf2_ros.  The file will have one of the following names:

    tf2_rosConfig.cmake
    tf2_ros-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  labust-ros-pkg/labust_mission/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:71 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package auv_msgs.

  Set auv_msgs_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for
  auv_msgs.  The file will have one of the following names:

    auv_msgsConfig.cmake
    auv_msgs-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  labust-ros-pkg/labust_mission/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:71 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package misc_msgs.

  Set misc_msgs_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
  for misc_msgs.  The file will have one of the following names:

    misc_msgsConfig.cmake
    misc_msgs-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  labust-ros-pkg/labust_mission/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


CMake Error at labust-ros-pkg/labust_mission/CMakeLists.txt:164 (decision_making_parsing):
  Unknown CMake command "decision_making_parsing".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195703/question-in-install-third-party-package-on-ros/) by [berry0511](https://answers.ros.org/users/14546/berry0511/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-10-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to install the dependencies of the packages you cloned. You can either download the source code for those dependencies into your workspace and build them or if you are on Ubuntu you can install the dependencies from `apt-get`.

You can try this (on Ubuntu):

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws
$ rosdep install --from-paths ./src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo
$ source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
$ catkin_make
```

Now obviously you'll want to replace `indigo` with the ROS distro you are using, but the above should install all the dependencies you need.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [berry0511](https://answers.ros.org/users/14546/berry0511/) on 2014-10-27**:
Thx for your answering but I'm not going to replace indigo , I have already installed groovy, and i want to install the package under groovy but i failed

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-10-27**:
@berry0511, you can use groovy, just replace `indigo` with `groovy` in the commands above.

**Comment by [berry0511](https://answers.ros.org/users/14546/berry0511/) on 2014-10-28**:
Ooops I misunderstood , I have tried the method above but it doesn't work..maybe there's something I've ignored, thank you very much for your patience.

**Comment by [berry0511](https://answers.ros.org/users/14546/berry0511/) on 2014-11-06**:
I have fix that! I downloaded the wrong package! thx a lot!